# Adding multiple GCP accounts to gcloud, configuring them and switching between them, by example

Tags: gcloud

I have two different GCP projects managed by two different organizations that are both tied to my email. Meaning when I log in to GCP Console I see them under my projects drop-downs.

I somehow (while onboarding with the first organization) configured my `gcloud` installation to successfully connect to the first org/project:

```
myuser ~ % gcloud config list
[compute]
region = us-east4
zone = us-east1-b
[core]
account = myemail@example.com
disable_usage_reporting = True
project = project-1

Your active configuration is: [default]


Updates are available for some Cloud SDK components.  To install them,
please run:
  $ gcloud components update



To take a quick anonymous survey, run:
  $ gcloud survey
```

I am now trying to add a configuration/project to my `gcloud` config so that I can switch back and forth between both projects throughout the day as needed:

```
myuser ~ % gcloud config configurations create project-2
Created [project-2].
Activated [project-2].
```

But now, when I go to list my available configurations I only see `project-2`:

```
myuser ~ % gcloud config list                               
[core]
disable_usage_reporting = True

Your active configuration is: [project-2]
```

**What command can I run to now view both project configurations? And how do I connect `project-2` to my email (`myemail@example.com`) and credentials?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a name other than `project-2` for the configuration as that could become confusing.

> **NOTE** My original answer was incorrect. Switching between configurations switches between active accounts but the list of authenticated accounts is preserved across configurations.

A configuration encapsulates a `gcloud` "environment". So, after creating a configuration, you'll need to e.g. `gcloud config set account` to set any *existing* (authenticated) accounts as active or `gcloud auth login` to *add* new accounts to the list.

> **NOTE** Once you've run `gcloud auth login` under any configuration, the list of accounts is preserved across all configurations but the *active* account is retained per configuration.

One challenge with setting configs is that `gcloud` commands become implicit, e.g. `gcloud compute instances delete my-instance` using configs could delete from the production project using the admin account if you're not careful to juggle `gcloud config` sets.

An alternative to configs (and my preference) is to always explicitly specify the configuration. Yes, it's more tedious and yes, you can still become complacent doing this, but I find it's more convenient:

i.e. always etc.

```sh
gcloud do-something \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--account=${ACCOUNT}
```

I strongly encourage you to set flags rather than use config when you're scripting `gcloud` commands. In this case, the additional typing is an up-front cost with a longer-term benefit of precision.

Another reason **not** to use configs. A configuration is globally applicable. If you use `gcloud` in multiple shells, changing the config in one shell, because it's global, will change the settings across shells (on the same machine).

Comment: Thanks @DazWilikin (+1), is there a `gcloud` command to list all the configurations (active or not) that I have setup on my machine?

Comment: You're welcome! `gcloud config configurations list`